# Heroku Postgres: Unhandled rejection Error: self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to configure the PostgreSQL database with postgrator in node, using the connectionString in production.  I've added the code for initialization in node

```
const postgrator = new Postgrator(migrationConfig);
postgrator.migrate('002', (err, migrations) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(migrations);
  }
  postgrator.endConnection();
});
```

```
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

let migrationConfig;
if (isDevelopment) {
  migrationConfig = {
    "migrationDirectory": "migrations",
    "driver": "pg",
    "host": process.env.DEV_DB_HOST,
    "port": process.env.DEV_DB_PORT,
    "database": process.env.DEV_DB_DATABASE,
    "username": process.env.DEV_DB_USER,
    "password": process.env.DEV_DB_PASS,
    "ssl": !isDevelopment,
  }
} else {
  migrationConfig = {
    "migrationDirectory": "migrations",
    "driver": "pg",
    "connectionString": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "ssl": true,
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the `self signed certificate` error on production.

```
2020-10-18T10:04:49.845485+00:00 app[web.1]: > export NODE_ENV=production && nodemon src/server.js
2020-10-18T10:04:49.845485+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-18T10:04:50.082326+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 2.0.4
2020-10-18T10:04:50.083611+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2020-10-18T10:04:50.084275+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
2020-10-18T10:04:50.084383+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
2020-10-18T10:04:50.085033+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
2020-10-18T10:04:50.489740+00:00 app[web.1]: Express is listening on port 48474
2020-10-18T10:04:50.535273+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection Error: self signed certificate
2020-10-18T10:04:50.535275+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1502:34)
2020-10-18T10:04:50.535276+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-10-18T10:04:50.535276+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
2020-10-18T10:04:50.535277+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:711:12)
2020-10-18T10:04:51.077573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

I've upgraded the dyno to a paid service to activate the SSL, yet this error still continues to come up.  I saw online suggestin to set `rejectUnauthorized` to false`, but postgrator does not provide that option.  Even if I set it to the Postgres configuration the issue seems to still persist.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello friend, I'm having the same issue. Did you find any solution?. I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27766627